# Using a Barracuda F400 Firewall Router Without a Modem

Tags: networking, router, firewall, modem, voip

I'm looking into a problem where VoIP phones don't ring for some of the incoming calls that I believe might be due to the network configuration.

Do you need a modem if you are using a Barracuda F400 Firewall Router and are there any problems that could arise if you use it without a modem?

Comment: You generally need a modem to access a WAN that you don't own.  Will you be accessing such a network?

Comment: Please explain this with more detail. What are you trying to do and what problems have you run into?

Comment: @CharlieRB - I've updated my question with more details. It is related to VoIP issues with the phone not ringing for any inbound calls.

Comment: You make is sound like you can make outgoing VOIP calls, so you already have a network connection. Correct? Are you dealing with a corporate network or home network?

Comment: That is correct. It is a corporate network. Also, it is some of the incoming calls that don't ring. Not all of them where it doesn't ring.